# Strange issue with websphere 8.5.5 transaction timeout + Spring tx 4.2.5

Tags: spring, timeout, websphere

I have this strange issue on a Websphere application server, but I don't manage to understand where does it come from.
I'm sorry if I don't explain it well.
The application server is configured with a transaction timeout at 60 seconds. 
Recently we added timeout to method annotated with transactional in spring

```
@Transactional(timeout=15)
```

From the time of the deployment it looks like all the methods annotated with transactional seems to have a transaction timeout of 15 seconds. 
We have checked and all methods involved in the transaction doesn't have any timeout in the annotation.

The application server is Websphere 8.5.5.11 with Spring Tx 4.2.5. 
We didn't try to reboot the server since it is in production.
Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. You have to explicitly set default timeout and not to automatically use that of the web server.

```
    ### TRANSACTION MANAGER ###

    <bean id="jtaTransactionManager"  class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" >
         <property name="globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultTimeout" value="120" />      
</bean>     



        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"  />
```

I don't know if it's a problem with spring tx library and interaction with websphere transaction manager.

**Update 30/03/2018**

We found that there was a bug in spring-tx at the current version, everything was solved by changing  the version to 4.3.12, anyway the solution I posted before works on the old version if you cannot upgrade your library.

Comment: you might have just saved our "soft sides" with this... to me the problem is on the websphere side btw, but I tent to "hate" WAS more  and more these days. big thank you!

Comment: Hi Eugene, I forgot to post what was our solution, I hope this helps!